# HTML drop down box add horizontal scroll bars

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Hi in HTML is there a way to add horizontal scroll bars to a drop down box? in firefox the box expands dynamically but IE doesnt, Iv tried google but with no success! Thank you.

```
<div class="filterform-row"> 
  <t:label for="networkGroup" /> 
  <t:select t:id="networkGroup" encoder="networkGroupEncoder" model="networkGroupsModel" blankOption="ALWAYS" class="expand"/> 
</div>

 div.filterform-row select { 
   background: transparent url(images/img13.gif) repeat-x scroll 0 0; 
   border: 1px solid silver; 
   color: #626262; 
   font-size: 11px; 
   margin: 5px; 
   width: 100px; 
   overflow-y: auto; 
   overflow-x: auto; 
   display:block; 
}
```

Comment: Could you add your html and css please?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably somehow set the width of the `select` element to a fixed size somewhere in your CSS.

Try adding this `style` property to your drop down:

```
<select ... style="width: auto;" />
```

This resets the element's width property to the default (auto); it should then render exactly as wide as it needs to be in all browsers.

Comment: I recommend using `width: auto !important;` to be sure the property specified in the `style` is used instead of something else.

Comment: @Albireo: Unless there's an `!important` width set already, that should not be necessary. The CSS properties set in `style` have higher priority than those set anywhere else.

Comment: True, but since it's just for testing purposes (and I've been hit by this - thanks, designers!) it won't do any harm, other than being totally sure it will behave like that.

Comment: @Albireo: Makes a lot of sense for testing, that's right. OTOH, the OP should probably get his hands on Firebug anyway to see where the styles are coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, adding auto makes the drop down box bigger when an item is selected which is good thanks. However the list of selectable items does not automatically grow with the width of the item.

Comment: @Matthew: That sounds quite odd. So the options in the dropdown are not as wide as the select box itself?

Comment: When I use css to grow the box 'width:auto;' the drop down list is the same size as the box however this looks ugly and im wanting the box to behave like it does in firefox i.e the box is say 100px but the drop down list grows in width so no text is cut off.